# Idiom or verb for "it didn't affect me the least bit"

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

I am looking for an idiom or a verb that is used to say: "it didn't affect at all" when, for example, talking about a movie that someone suggested to me for being funny and then when I watched it, it turned out not to be funny at all similar to "it wasn't half funny"

What can I say to fill in the blank here:
"It/I didn't _________" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. What can I say to fill in the blank here:

"It/I didn't _________" ?

---

A. **It didn't *"do it for me"*.**

References in periodicals archive ? After surveying a newly-decorated room, he commented: ``It doesn't do it for me. Ref [Paddy Shennan: Weekend TV; thefreedictionary.com](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Do+it+for+me)

P.S. do not get confused with the Acronym DIFM - "*do it for me*"

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't my cup of tea.
It wasn't my thing.
It didn't work for me.
It wasn't up my alley.

The following might fit a little better your original meaning of "It didn't *affect* me" but in recent usage they also have sexual connotations, especially the second one, so be careful:

It didn't get me going.
It didn't turn me on.